# Pass a variable to components in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm stuck with a problem that may be very simple but can't get the solution. I got a page that pass an array of components to a child component.

Here is the page :

**mainPage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Comp1 from "comps/comp1"
import Comp2 from "comps/comp2"
import MyChildComponent from "child/childComponenent"

const MyPage = () => {

let arr = [<Comp1/>, <Comp2/>]

<ChildComponent comps={arr} />

}

export MyPage
```

The Comp1 looks like this (Comp2 looks more or like the same, with different text) :

**comp1.js**

```
import React from "react";
export const Roue = ({ step }) => (
<p>Here is the step {step} </p>
)
```

And finally I want to access those comps in the child component

**childComponenent.js**

```
import React from "react";

const MyChildComponent = ({comps}) => {

const FirstComp = comps[0]
const FirstCompProp = <FirstComp step={1}/>

//console.log(FirstCompProp) works fine

return (
//got an error
{FirstCompProp}
)

}

export MyPage
```

So I can't render the comps in the child component with the prop, I got this error :

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

What did I get wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `TheComp1`?

Comment: It's a const that returns a svg code inline

Comment: You have a number of problems: You are importing as if there was a default export, but you only have a named export in `comps1.js` so it would need to be `import {Roue} from "comps/comp1"` , then you are invoking the component when assigning it in the array, you need to just pass the reference to the imported function. Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-flower-sht7jh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstComp` is already an invoked *React component* that returns JSX.

You should change

```
let arr = [<Comp1/>, <Comp2/>]
```

to

```
let arr = [Comp1, Comp2]
```